# Make arecord ignore aplay

Tags: audio, alsa

I'm trying to create a kind of robot on my raspberry pi to answer my questions.

At first I made it so that it only answered when it heard it's name, and it worked fine. But now I'm adding more natural conversations, and I've stumbled upon a problem.

Whenever the bot speaks with the aplay command, the arecord command captures its own voice and sends to the bot to process. The bot cannot distinguish between my and its own voice, so it starts talking to itself in loop (quite funny, I must add).

I made a check on my bot code to verify if what was heard was exactly the same as what as said (after I converted it to text), but that doesn't work very well (sometimes it understands itself with little variations), and takes some extra processing time just to find that out, time in which my own commands are not processed because it's trying to find out if the voice it hears was its own.

I'm wondering if there is a way to make an instance of arecord ignore what an instance of aplay said in the same machine. I believe a more low-level solution is definitely possible (I'm thinking how I can use skype without headphones, for instance; it doesn't need to use voice recognition to know not to infinite loop my friend's voice).

I'm looking for a solution for some time, but I can't seem to find any mention of this problem (that seems to be should be very common). Maybe I just don't know the name of the phenomena. Thoughts?

Comment: There are entire university programs designed around this specific problem.

Comment: Does the sound device internally route the playback stream to the capture stream, or does the microphone hear what the speaker outputs?

Comment: @CL. The latter; the bot speaks through a speaker and the mic captures her own voice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the problem is that `arecord` captures via the mic the sound of the speakers which you control with `aplay`, possibly with a delay:

The keyword you are looking for is **echo cancellation**. There is existing software for that both for ALSA and Pulseaudio, used e.g. in Smartphones that are based on Linux.

Basically, the algorithm has to correlate the received input with the sent output to measure the delay and determine the volume, and then subtract the output from the input with the correct delay and scaling to cancel it.